# Prove a piecewise function is continuous

Tags: continuity, connectedness

As part of a larger question regarding proving a subset is not connected, so I have $S=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : xy=1\}$ and I have said this is not connected as the function below:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x>0\\ 0 & x<0\\ \end{cases}$$ is a surjective, continuous function that maps $f:S\to\{0,1\}$

So I now want to show $f(x)$ is continuous, I have attempted to use $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=f(a)$ but I can't work out how to get this written out and what values of $x$ I need to take? I'm also doubting whether this is continuous but for all values of $x$ would not include $0$ as it cannot take this value?

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Points in $S$ are pairs. So if you want to define a function $f \colon S → \{0,1\}$, you need to specify what the value of $f\big((x,y)\big)$ is. (We write shorter $f(x,y)$.) Probably
$$
f( (x,y) ) = \begin{cases} 1 & x > 0 \\ 0 & x < 0 \end{cases}
$$
Now you want to show
$$\lim_{S \ni (x, y) → (a, b)} f(x, y) = f(a,b)$$
for all $(a,b) ∈ S$.
So let $(x_n, y_n)$ a sequence converging to $(a,b) ∈ S$. This implies that $x_n → a$. If $a = 0$, then $ab = 0$, so $(a,b) \notin S$. So $a < 0$ or $a> 0$. In both cases, $x_n$ must have the same sign as $a$ for all sufficiantly big $n$, so $f((x, y)) = f((a,b))$. Therefore $\lim_{(x, y) → (a,b)} f(x,y) = f(a,b)$. $f$ is continous.

Comment: But you could also just say, that $\{(x,y) ∈ ℝ^2 | y = 0\} ∩ S = \emptyset$ but $S$ has points on either side of the line, so it must be disconnected.

Comment: Just so you know my friend: if you want the set brackets to appear in MatJax for the set $\{0,1\}$ as the codomain of $f$ you can type \{0,1\} with the backslashes (of course all enclosed in $$).

Comment: Generally I am aware, but this time I missed it. Thanks.